# SciPy PearsonR ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: numpy, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm running into some issues while using the `pearsonr` method from SciPy.  I tried to keep it as simple as possible (note gorgeous N^2 loop), but still I'm running up against this problem.  I don't entirely understand where I'm going wrong.  my arrays are getting selected correctly, and have the same dimensionality.

The code I run is:

```
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer, Binarizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

ny_cluster = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(ny_raw.clusterid.values)
ny_vocab = Binarizer().fit_transform(CountVectorizer().fit_transform(ny_raw.text.values))

ny_vc_phi = np.zeros((ny_vocab.shape[1], ny_cluster.shape[1]))
for i in xrange(ny_vc_phi.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(ny_vc_phi.shape[1]):
        ny_vc_phi[i,j] = stats.pearsonr(ny_vocab[:,i].todense(), ny_cluster[:,j])[0]
```

Which produces the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/data/TweetClusters/TweetsLocationBayesClf/<ipython-input-29-ff1c3ac4156d> in <module>()
      3 for i in xrange(ny_vc_phi.shape[0]):
      4     for j in xrange(ny_vc_phi.shape[1]):
----> 5         ny_vc_phi[i,j] = stats.pearsonr(ny_vocab[:,i].todense(), ny_cluster[:,j])[0]
      6 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.pyc in pearsonr(x, y)
   2201     # Presumably, if abs(r) > 1, then it is only some small artifact of floating

   2202     # point arithmetic.

-> 2203     r = max(min(r, 1.0), -1.0)
   2204     df = n-2
   2205     if abs(r) == 1.0:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I really don't understand where this selection is going on.  Of course it doesn't help that I don't know how the r variable is getting calculated.  Could it be that I am somehow messing up my inputs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that the arguments to `pearsonr` are *one-dimensional* arrays.  That is, both `ny_vocab[:,i].todense()` and `ny_cluster[:,j]` should be 1-d.  Try:

```
    ny_vc_phi[i,j] = stats.pearsonr(ny_vocab[:,i].todense().ravel(), ny_cluster[:,j].ravel())[0]
```

(I added a call to `ravel()` to each of the arguments of `pearsonr`.)

Comment: This was really close to my solution, so I'm marking it as answered.  For anyone wondering, I was using a sparse matrix, so there was an array cast that needed to be included.  For anyone wondering, the line verbatim was `ny_vc_phi[i,j] = stats.pearsonr(np.squeeze(np.asarray(ny_vocab[:,i].todense())), ny_cluster[:,j])[0]`

Comment: I was about to edit the question and suggest `squeeze`  as an alternative, if the problem was simply a "trivial" dimension, but you beat me to it. :-)