# Pearson correlation matrix in Python, ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, correlation, python-xarray, pearson

I'm trying to get a matrix, (lat, lon) size, with the Pearson Coefficient value for every grid point, for

x : a 3D DataArray (time, lat, lon) (time size is 30)

y : a DataArray column vector with a 30 values series inside

So i would like to calculate the pearson coefficient for every (lat,lon) for a column vector of 30 elements for x.

I tried:

```
corrmap = xr.DataArray(x2)
for i in range(len(corrmap['lat']))
     for j in range(len(corrmap['lon']))
          corrmap[i, j], p_value = pearsonr(x[:, i, j], y)
```

but i get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

that i cannot perfectly understand in the meaning. Is my method uncorrect? Should i use another type of code to solve my problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `y.shape`?  (I'm assuming that a `DataArray` object has a `shape` attribute.)

Comment: Is `pearsonr` imported from `scipy.stats`?  If not, where is it defined?

Comment: sorry I forgot to say that y.shape is (30, 1), so a column vector. And yes I did, i correctly imported pearsonr from scipy.stats

Comment: *"... y.shape is (30, 1), so a column vector."*  That's the problem.  See @JulianGiles' answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using `y` and it has two dimensions, pearsonr can't handle that. Specify `y[:,0]` and it works. That is:

```
corrmap = np.zeros(((len(corrmap['lat']), len(corrmap['lon'])))

for i in range(len(corrmap['lat'])):
     for j in range(len(corrmap['lon'])):
          corrmap[i, j], p_value = pearsonr(x[:, i, j], y[:,0])
```

Also I would just use a numpy array for the coefficients instead of an xarray, at least to get the values, then you can convert it to xarray.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [scipy.stats.pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html). The arguments to PearsonR should be *one-dimensional* arrays.

So give a go to:

```
corrmap[i, j], p_value = pearsonr(x[:, i, j].ravel(), y)
```

What ravel() does is return contiguous flattened array,
[Numpy ravel()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)

Here is also a bit of context around the error that you are getting, [evaluate array in boolean context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063039/2103431). In other words, the extra dimension is probably causing some operations to be applied to an array instead of a scalar.
This issue is of the same nature as yours: [SO: PearsonR ValueError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28841313/2103431)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes i correctly imported pearsonr from scipy.stats.

Anyway, making the correction you suggest (that i understand and approve) i get an AttributeError, because of the fact that "'DataArray object' has no attribute 'ravel'.


Is it a mistake to inizialize corrmap at the beginning as a xr.DataArray with a (lat, lon) shape?

Answer (score 0):

You can calutate the **Pearson correlation** coefficient using:

```
import numpy
numpy.corrcoef(list1, list2)[0, 1]
```